# MongoDB sort documents by array elements

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have document structure like :

```js
{
    map: 'A',
    points: [
        {
            type: 'type1',
            distanceToSpawn: 110
        },
        {
            type: 'type4',
            distanceToSpawn: 40
        },
        {
           type: 'type6',
           distanceToSpawn: 30
        }
    ]
},
{
    map: 'B',
    points: [
        {
            type: 'type1',
            distanceToSpawn: 100
        },
        {
            type: 'type2',
            distanceToSpawn: 60
        },
        {
            type: 'type3',
            distanceToSpawn: 25
        }
    ]
},
{
    map: 'C',
    points: [
        {
            type: 'type2',
            distanceToSpawn: 90
        },
        {
            type: 'type3',
            distanceToSpawn: 1
        },
        {
            type: 'type6',
            distanceToSpawn: 76
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to get all maps having point type `type1` sorted by the `distanceToSpawn` in ascending order.

Expected result :

```js
{
    map: 'B',
    points: [
        {
            type: 'type1',
            distanceToSpawn: 100
        }
    ]
},
{
    map: 'A',
    points: [
        {
            type: 'type1',
            distanceToSpawn: 110
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried something like :

```js
db.maps.find({'points.type': {$eq : 'type1'}}, {map: 1, 'points.$':1}).sort({'points.distanceToSpawn': 1}).limit(10)
```

But this thing not sorting maps by ascending order.

Thanks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You cannot do that with arrays, and the main problem here is because you want the "sort" to happen on the matched element. If you want to sort results like this then you need to use [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) instead. Either as:

For modern MongoDB versions:

```js
db.maps.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "points.type": "type1" }},
    { "$addFields": {
        "order": {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$points",
              "as": "p",
              "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$p.type", "type1" ] }
            }
        }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "order": 1 } }
])
```

For MongoDB 2.6 to 3.0

```js
db.maps.aggregate([
   { $match: { 'points.type': 'type1' } },
    {
     $project: {
       points: {
        $setDifference: [
          {
            $map: {
              input: '$points',
              as: 'p',
              in: {
                $cond: [
                  { $eq: ['$$p.type', 'type1'] },
                  '$$p',
                  false,
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          [false]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { 'points.distanceToSpawn': 1 } },
]);
```

Or less efficiently in versions prior to MongoDB 2.6:

```js
db.maps.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "points.type": "type1" }},
    { "$unwind": "$points" },
    { "$match": { "points.type": "type1" }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "points": { "$push": "$points" }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "points.ditanceToSpawn": 1 } }         
])
```

That's the only way to match the correct elements and have them considered in a "sort" operation. The default cursor sort will just otherwise consider the values for the field in the array elements that do not match your selected "type" instead.

Comment: Keep in mind that when using `$unwind` operator before the `$sort` operator it cannot take advantages of an index. (I had the same issues trying to sort by array filds using always the first item of the array for comparism.)

Comment: For the "modern MongoDB versions" example, should the `sort` be on `order.distanceToSpawn` instead of just `order`? Or if not, why?

Comment: What index would you create for this sorting ?