# How to sort documents based on $in order?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have array of ObjectIds like the following:

`var list = [{_id: ObjectId(1)}, {_id: ObjectId(2)}, {_id: ObjectId(3)}];`

I need to query these documents by the following query:

```
Post.find({_id: {$in: list}}).exec(function (err, posts) {
    console.log(posts);
});
```

But unfortunately the order of `posts` is random. What is the best way to make proper order based on `list` array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for that problem we have two options:

1. Sort client side
2. Sort using aggregation framework as per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889240/mongodb-sort-documents-by-array-elements)

   db.x.aggregate:([{ $sort:{ list:1 }}])

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I can't sort by using aggregate becase I query documents by _id and don't have their context

Comment: @Erik - so only client side sorting can be applied or save the documents in required order :-)