# MongoDB 2.6: filter fields in aggregation (alternative to $function)

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44669081/mongodb-sort-by-nested-object-field-part-of-array) I asked how to sort documents by array elements in MongoDB.

Now I have to filter elements in result. In particular I want to exclude unnecessary fields. I found the [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) function but works only in MongoDB version greather than 3.2

Here the example

Sample collection

```
[
   {
      "_id":ObjectId("5695128ee4b04403440b61c2"),
      "_class":"com.acme.entity.Company",
      "name":"Company Name A",
      "countries":[
         {
            "country_code":"a.b.c",
            "country_name":"Italy",
            "country_weight":4
         },
         {
            "country_code":"b.c.d",
            "country_name":"Germany",
            "country_weight":4
         },
         {
            "country_code":"c.d.e",
            "country_name":"France",
            "country_weight":3
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "_id":ObjectId("292829287293bcbe440b22bb"),
      "_class":"com.acme.entity.Company",
      "name":"Company Name B",
      "countries":[
         {
            "country_code":"a.b.c",
            "country_name":"Italy",
            "country_weight":6
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "_id":ObjectId("99922222bbeecc3339900000"),
      "_class":"com.acme.entity.Company",
      "name":"Company Name C",
      "countries":[
         {
            "country_code":"a.b.c",
            "country_name":"Italy",
            "country_weight":9
         },
         {
            "country_code":"c.d.e",
            "country_name":"France",
            "country_weight":3
         },
         {
            "country_code":"l.h.i",
            "country_name":"Holland",
            "country_weight":8
         },
         {
            "country_code":"e.n.g",
            "country_name":"England",
            "country_weight":1
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Query to filter and sort data based on country_weight field

```
db.companies.aggregate([
    { $match: { "countries.country_code": "a.b.c"}},
    { $project: {
        name : 1,
        countries: "$countries",
        aggregatefunction: { 
            $setDifference: [
                { $map: {
                    "input": "$countries",
                    "as": "p",
                    "in": { $cond: [
                            { "$eq": [ "$$p.country_code", "$01.01.01" ] },
                        "$$p",
                        false
                    ]}
                }},
                [false]   
            ]
        }
    }},
    { $sort: { "countries.country_weight": -1 } }
])
```

With this solution I got in resulting countries field all the company country. I want to filter the countries field to obtain only the filtered country.

Comment: Keep [reading the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889240/mongodb-sort-documents-by-array-elements) then because there is also `$unwind`. If that's what your version supports and you do not have "distinct" items then that is what you use.

Comment: Thank you @neil, it works like expected. I noticed that the "unwinded" return field is correct if I execute the query on MongoDB 2.6, but differs in MongoDB 3.0. Why this different behavior?

Comment: I would suggest there actually is no difference and you probably have a small error in there. If you feel the need to ask the question though, then [Ask a new Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). But please check that your question is not already answered in an existing response first.