# mongodb aggregate + order by sub array value of specific element + skip + limit

Tags: arrays, mongodb, pagination, aggregation-framework

something is wrong with my aggregation function. I get duplicate elements.

I try it with this: [MongoDB sort documents by array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889240/mongodb-sort-documents-by-array-elements)

```
console.log('####');
console.log('offset', offset);
console.log('pageSize', pageSize);
ProcedureModel.aggregate([
    { $match: { 'history.initiator': '2. Beratung' } },
    {
      $addFields: {
        order: {
          $arrayElemAt: [
            {
              $filter: {
                input: '$history',
                as: 'p',
                cond: { $eq: ['$$p.initiator', '2. Beratung'] },
              },
            },
            0,
          ],
        },
      },
    },
    { $sort: { 'order.date': -1 } },
    { $skip: offset },
    { $limit: pageSize },
  ]).then((res) => {
    res.forEach((r, i) => console.log(`${i}: `, r._id));
    return res;
  });
```

My objects looks like this

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a75a91ea57539646d00be29"),
"procedureId" : "81080",
"history" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a75a91d4a5aa5541db67598"),
        "initiator" : "Änderung der Ausschussüberweisung",
        "date" : ISODate("2017-06-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a75a91d4a5aa5541db67597"),
        "initiator" : "Beschlussempfehlung und Bericht,  Urheber : Ausschuss für Recht und Verbraucherschutz",
        "date" : ISODate("2017-06-28T00:00:00.000Z")
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a75a91d4a5aa5541db67596"),
        "initiator" : "2. Beratung",
        "date" : ISODate("2017-06-30T00:00:00.000Z"),
        …
    }, 
    …
],
…
```

}

and this is my result. there are two duplicate results :(

```
####
offset 0
pageSize 3
0:  5a75a91ea57539646d00be29
1:  5a75a91ea57539646d00bdb6
2:  5a75a91ea57539646d00bab7
####
offset 3
pageSize 3
0:  5a75a91ea57539646d00be65
1:  5a75a91ea57539646d00be29
2:  5a75a91ea57539646d00bab7
####
offset 6
pageSize 3
0:  5a75a91ea57539646d00b9eb
1:  5a75a91ea57539646d00bba5
2:  5a75a91ea57539646d00bb9f
```

why did have the second request two results of the first request, and the third none of the previous? and how I set up a correct offset and limit?

Comment: Kindly paste the documents that are returned with the query `ProcedureModel.aggregate([
    { $match: { 'history.initiator': '2. Beratung' } }]).exec((err, docs) => console.log(docs));`

Comment: the result without skip and limit is correct:
    0:  5a75c209a57539646d00c6a4
    1:  5a75c209a57539646d00c6a6
    2:  5a75c209a57539646d00c6ae
    3:  5a75c209a57539646d00c6b6
    4:  5a75c66ca57539646d00cb7f
    5:  5a75c66ca57539646d00ce26
    6:  5a75c66ca57539646d00ced7
    7:  5a75c66ca57539646d00cee5
    8:  5a75c66ca57539646d00cef2
    9:  5a75c66ca57539646d00cf34
    10:  5a75c66ca57539646d00cac2

(i reimport my data, so the id's are different)